# Conditional subsequent request with RxJava

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I have an issue with my network client design. I have a use case, when the client tries to request an item from a REST API, but in case the API returns a 404 HTTP status code I need to send a request to create the item on the server and then request the item again.

I would like to use RxJava to avoid the callback hell. Is this a valid use case RxJava? Is it possible to create such a conditional sub-request?

Thank you for your time and answers.

Comment: absolutely, depending on your rest client (retrofit, I suppose?), the 404 will fall in an onError. You can catch it in `onErrorReturn` or in `doOnError` to return a different thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question, I assume you have something that look like

```
public Observable<Item> getItem();
```

that will either return the item, or fire an error and

```
public Observable<?> createItem();
```

That will create one.

You can use those two together like so:

```
public Observable<Item> getOrCreateItem() {
    return getItem().onErrorResumeNext(error -> {
        // Depending on your framework, figure out which is the result code
        if (error.getResultCode() == 404) {
            return createItem().flatMap(ignored -> getItem());
        } else {
            return Observable.error(error);
        }
    });
}
```

With Retrofit, you'd have to simply make sure the exception is a `RetrofitError`, cast it, and get the response and the status code. (`((RetrofitError) error).getResponse().getStatus()`)